# PySide2 receivers signature

Tags: python, pyqt5, pyside, pyside2

I am experiencing a strange problem with QObject().receivers method.

```
import sys

from PySide2.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMessageBox, QWidget
from PySide2.QtCore import Slot, Signal, SIGNAL


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)

    widget = QWidget()
    signal = Signal()

    print(widget.receivers(signal))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

It works under PyQt5, but fails under PySide2 with the following error:

```
TypeError: 'PySide2.QtCore.QObject.receivers' called with wrong argument types:
  PySide2.QtCore.QObject.receivers(Signal)
Supported signatures:
  PySide2.QtCore.QObject.receivers(bytes)
```

There is a weird workaround:

```
print(widget.receivers(SIGNAL("signal()")))
```

But I don't understand how it works and it's hardly maintainable.

Maybe someone have experience with **receivers** usage in PySide2?
I'm using the latest version from pip.

Comment: Signals are bound to class instances, meaning that they are defined at class level and become bound to the instance once it's created. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Unlike PyQt5/6, PySide2/6 still supports both [traditional and new-style signal syntax](https://wiki.qt.io/Qt_for_Python_Signals_and_Slots). The reason why PyQt dropped the traditional syntax is because it's verbose, error-prone and unpythonic. I suppose you'd have to ask the PySide devs why they continue to support it. And you could also ask them why it's not possible to pass a `SignalInstance` to `QObject.receivers()`, because it certainly looks like a strange omission. PyQt signal objects have attributes which hold the C++ signature(s), so `SIGNAL()` isn't needed.

Comment: @musicamante, this code is just a proof of incorrect PySide2 behavior.